# thread конструктор. Передача параметров функции

Tags: c++

Имеется класс `CMMap`, у него имеется метод `view`. Пытаюсь "делегировать" выполнение этого метода в тред. Вываливается ошибка:

> Ошибка C2661 нет перегруженной функции, принимающей 2 аргументов

Код:

```cpp
class CMMap : private "какой шаблонный класс с определёнными аргументами"
    {
    public:
        void view() {};
    };
}

int main()
{
    CMMap mm;
    std::thread th(std::mem_fn(&CMMap::view), mm);

    th.detach();
    th.~thread();
    return 0;
}
```

*Может вопрос и глупый, но битый день не могу выяснить причину.
Притом компилится в таком виде:*

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    template <TN T>
    auto f(T a) {
        return a;
    }

};

void main()
{
    std::thread th(std::mem_fn(&A::f<int>), A(), 4);
    th.detach();
}
```

Comment: я не совсем понял: у вас ошибка компиляции или выполнениея?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вангую: базовый класс `CMMap` запрещает копирование. Если я прав, то сделайте так (тем более наверняка вы имели ввиду именно это когда писали код):

```cpp
    std::thread th(std::mem_fn(&CMMap::view), std::ref(mm));
```

Нужно явно указать, что вы передаете аргумент по ссылке, а не по значению

Comment: Действительно, базовый класс запрещает копирование. Спасибо.

Comment: Исправил. Вылезла ошибка линкера LNK2019 и LNK1120.
Как быть?

Comment: @SpaghettiMan текст ошибок приведите

Comment: Ошибка LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: void __thiscall cha::CMMap::view(void)" (?view@CMMap@cha@@QAEXXZ) в функции _main

Comment: @SpaghettiMan без приведения полного кода вряд ли сдесь можно что сказать

Comment: Извиняюсь. Мой прокол. Забыл указать реализацию у функции `view`. Скомпилилось.
Ещё маленький вопрос: есть ли разница при передаче с `&` и `std::ref()`?

Comment: @SpaghettiMan последнюю часть не понял

Comment: По аналогии с вашим исправлением: есть ли разница передаю в конструктор `std::thread` экземпляр некопируемого класса как `std::ref(mm)` и `&mm`. И, если есть, то какая?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104938/discussion-between-spaghetti-man-and-andrej-levkovitch).

Comment: @SpaghettiMan для начала второй вариант работать не будет. Не следует забывать, что `&` обозначает ссылку только в аргументах объявления функций и объявлениях переменных, иначе это взятие указателя

Comment: В первом случае mem_fm примет экземпляр класса как указатель. Во втором как указатель в обёртке врапера. В чем же разница?

Comment: @SpaghettiMan я не знаком (никогда не использовал) `mem_fn` так что точно не знаю как это работает, но в первом случае он принимает не указатель на экземпляр класса, а ссылку на экземпляр класса - это разные вещи.